# do a plain old form submit with angular

Tags: html, angular

I want to do a plain old form submit within my angular app, e.g. with this code:

```
<form method="post" action="http://other-server/">
  <input name="something"
         value="somevalue"/>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

So I put this into my components template, but nothing is submitted when I push the button.

The reason why I want this is because http://other-server/ does not send any *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* headers, so I cannot process the response in javascript.

Comment: I think you have to add ngNoForm to your form element. That prevents angular from trying to automatically consider the form to be an Angular form.

Answer (score 3):

MikeOne is correct.

Add `ngNoForm` to your form

```html
<form ngNoForm method="post" action="http://other-server/">
  <input name="something"
         value="somevalue"/>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that's nice, but so I have to use the submit button. I want tu submit it by javascript. So I put it into my index.html and operate with document.getElementbyID. As it is a hidden form, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
<form #form action='http://other-server/' method='post'>
    <input name="something"
     value="somevalue"/>
    <button type="submit" (click)="form.submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```